# Difference between `&`, `(PTYPE)` and `(PTYPE)&`

Tags: c++

By examining the following code i can't tell what is the difference between the three approaches, they simply return the address, (which is a `PINT`) so can i consider them the same ?

```
double *x = new double;
*x = 5.5;
cout << x << endl;
cout << &x << endl;
cout << (int*)x << endl;
cout << (int*)&x << endl;
cout << *(int*)&x << endl;
cout << *&x << endl;
```

if casting to `(int*)` for example returns the address is that mean that using `(int*)&x` is equal to `*&x`, it doesn't seem to be that as the former gives me an intPTR not an INT

Also may someone refer me to a book that covers pointers and references in an easy way ?

Comment: what is `PINT` ?  (don't say 600ml)

Comment: @MattMcNabb :D lol what ? it is an int* right ?

Comment: `*&x` is just like `x` since the `*` and the `&` are opposite to each other. `*x` is the value stored in the address stored in `x` (if x is a pointer it make sense). &x is the address of the variable x. the PINT just cast x to a pointer, so obviously it will give a pointer result.

Comment: @SHR so can you tell me what will be the difference between these ? (updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> they simply return the address, (which is a PINT) so can i consider them the same ?

Assuming `PINT` is `typedef`ed to something along the lines of `pointer to an int`,

```
typedef int* PINT;
```

The lines

```
cout << typeid((PINT)&x).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(&x).name() << endl;
```

should be expected to print type info corresponding to `int*`. The middle line, however, is strange.

```
cout << typeid((PINT)x).name() << endl;
```

Regardless of that `x` is, you are performing a compile time cast to `PINT`. Of course, the type being passed to `typeid` is `PINT`. That explains why you are getting the same output for all three lines.

You could use:

```
double d;
cout << typeid((PINT)d).name() << endl;
```

and expect to get the same answer. You are coercing the type `PINT` on the `typeid` operator.

Comment: but i think casting a double to Pint won't compile, i will test and see.